# Is this javascript code pattern is good?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am working on a multi-tenant appointment scheduling application using [Asp.net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/). I want help in javascript code pattern decision. I have the following scenario:

I am getting the complex ViewModel (*name: TenantModel*) from server and in javascript i am using [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for creating the knockout Model.

Let see what i have in my TenantModel:

TenantModel contains various complex types such as:

- List<EmployeeModel>
- List<CustomerModel>
- List<ServicesModel>
- ProfileModel
- and many more..

These complex types can further contain complex types such as:

- EmployeeModel contains the list of Services comes under his jurisdiction.
- ProfileModel contains ContactModel

First i will tell my efforts:

I have decided to use [Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) in javascript code. So currently in am thinking to structure my javascript code something like this:

```
var profile = (function () {

    var _viewmodel;

    var initialize = function () {
        //initialize _viewmodel here
    };

    var bind = function (node) {
        ko.applyBindings(_viewmodel, node);
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize,
        bind: bind
    };

})();


var employee = (function () {

    var _viewmodel;

    var initialize = function () {
        //initialize _viewmodel here
    };

    var bind = function (node) {
        ko.applyBindings(_viewmodel, node);
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize,
        bind: bind
    };

})();


var tenant = (function () {

    var _viewmodel;

    var initialize = function (jsonTenantModel) {
        _viewmodel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonTenantModel, {
            'Profile': {
                create: function (option) {
                    //create Profile using profile module
                }
            },
            'Employees': {
                create: function (option) {
                    //create Employees using Employee module
                }
            }
        })
    };

    var bind = function (node) {
        ko.applyBindings(_viewmodel, node);
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize,
        bind: bind
    };

})();
```

Guys i am not an experience javascript programmer but i want to write an extensible and manageable javascript code. I want to know that is i am thinking in  correct direction ? Or is there any other better way to achieve this kind of scenario ??

Comment: Your models seem far too complex. You should only pass the data that each view will actually use and requires.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to whip JavaScript into behaving like C++. This will make your code heavy and cumbersome. I would not recomend that approach at all.

Comment: Actually i have a tenant dashboard where tenant can manage all its data like customers, services, employees etc there so that view is something like singlepage app that's why i am transferring all tenant data on that view

Comment: Yeah, sounds more like: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2013/05/private-properties-in-es6-and-es3-and.html , making a fully fledged OOP out of javascript. ;)

Comment: @dollarvar your suggested link is broken

Comment: I guess it interpreted the `,` after the URL as address.

Comment: @dollarvar yes you are right

Comment: @kuroi neko Can you explain how the revealing module pattern is implemented in C++? I am very curious

Comment: @XGreen This was just meant as a small joke. The only common ground between this "Module pattern" thing and the beasts that dwell behind the C++ syntactic sugar crust is the dream of generic solutions, usually leading to overly complex, obfuscated and cumbersome code.

Answer (score 1):

your approach for using the RMP with knockout is a good decision. And will go a long way in helping your keeping your app scalable and manageable. However your modules looks too complex for purpose.

There are few things you need to consider as well.

1. How are you going to handle dependencies within your modules? Perhaps think about using require.js?
2. How will your modules communicate between each other (if they need to)? Do you need to implement a messaging system (which itself would be a module)
3. Do you want your app to be a single page (This requires a whole new set of consideration) one or classic multipage approach?

But what is good practice would be keeping those models separate from their view models, preferably in whole separate files, which you optimize and combine for production.

It's an easy way think of your viewmodels as the collection holder and members in those collections are your models.

```
// Sketch of employee model
function Employee(data){
    var self = this;
    self.FirstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName);
    self.LastName = ko.observable(data.LastName);
    self.FullName = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.FirstName() + ' ' + self.LastName();
    });
}

// Sketch of a possible list of employees
// This viewmodel now will have a dependency on the Emplyee model
// So if you have for example require.js you can go:

// dataservice could be another module which you create to separate data calls 
// from your business logic

require(["models/employee", "services/dataservice"], function(employee, dataservice) {
    // and now employee model is availbale with this context:

    function EmployeesList(data){
        var self = this;
        self.employees = ko.observableArray();
        self.editDetails = function(employee){
            // code for editing employee
        }
        self.activate = function(){
            // So you can now add new employees in the 
            // collection based on your model
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(item){
                self.employees.push(new employee(item))
            });
        }
        return {
            employees: self.employees,
            activate: self.activate
        }
    }

    // a data service which might have a getEmployees method which can take options like MinAge:
    dataservice.getEmployees({ 'MinAge' : 36  }, function(employeeData){

        var myEmployeesList = new EmployeesList(employeeData)

        // You might get tired of calling activate all the time for your view modules
        // And also feel you have to deal with the area they might effect
        // If you use a SPA framework (if you are making spa) then they usually have
        // a automatic mechanism for activating modules and applying the binding e.g. Durandal.js
        myEmployeesList.activate();

        ko.applyBindings(myEmployeesList);
        // or
        ko.applyBindings(myEmployeesList, $('#employeesContainer')[0]);
    });
});
```

Some reading material:

[SPA JumpStart – Architecture](http://www.johnpapa.net/spajs02/)